# Azure Data factory and Data flow taking too much time to process data from staging to Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So I have one data factory which runs every day, and it selects data from oracle on-premise database around 80M records and moves it to parquet file, which is taking around 2 hours I want to speed up this process... also the data flow process which insert and update data in db

parquet file setting

[image: taking to much time enter image description here]

Next step is from parquet file it call the data flow which move data as upsert to database but this also taking too much time

data flow  Setting

[image]

Let me know which compute type for data flow

Memory Optimized 
Computed Optimized 
General Purpose

[image]

[image]

**After Round Robin**  Update

[image]

Sink Time

[image]

Comment: I have updated the process and optimized using Round Robin and selected 10 partitions. and Also adding new images the good thing is that from source to it is taking 1 min but a sink to DB is taking 48 mins, but the overall process is taking 111 Mins still :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you open the monitoring detailed execution plan for the data flow? Click on each stage in your data flow and look to see where the bulk of the time is being spent. You should see on the top of the view how much time was spent setting-up the compute environment, how much time was taken to read your source, and also check the total write time on your sinks.

I have some examples of how to view and optimize this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QasncXQjLow).

Comment: Thanks @Mark check the last image

Comment: It took 6 mins to start-up the Spark cluster and 45 mins to write to your database (stage time in Sink). What is the total end-to-end execution time for the data flow?

Comment: I have Updated the new process

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would surmise that 45 min to stuff 85M files into a SQL DB is not horrible.  You can break the task down into chunks and see what's taking the longest time to complete.  Do you have access to Databricks?  I do a lot of pre-processing with Databricks, and I have found Spark to be super-super-fast!!  If you can pre-process in Databricks and push everything into your SQL world, you may have an optimal solution there.

Comment: Thanks i am looking in the spark :)

Comment: I have Updated the new process

Comment: Using Spark now?

Comment: I've found that you can spend countless hours doing something the wrong way, but if it's the only way you know, you get stuck doing it that way.  Or, spend a few hours doing some research, figure out a better way to do things, and then save yourself countless hours, well into the future.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#partitioning-on-sink can you try modifying your `partition` settings under `Optimize` tab of your Sink ?

I faced similar issue with the default partitioning setting, where the data load was taking close to 30+ mins for 1M records itself, after changing the partition strategy to `round robin` and provided number of partitions as `5` (for my case) load is happening in less than a min.

Try experimenting with both Source partition (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#partitioning-on-source) & Sink partition settings to come up with the optimum strategy. That should improve the data load time

Comment: I have Updated the new process